Which distributions make independence and independence of means equivalent?
Suppose $(X,Y)$ is a random vector defined on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. The following implications are true:
$$
X\perp Y \Rightarrow 
 \mathbb E[Y|X]= \mathbb E[Y] 
$$
Besides, If $(X,Y)$ is a Gaussian random vector then these notions are equivalent:
$$
X\perp Y \Leftrightarrow  
 \mathbb E[Y|X]= \mathbb E[Y] 
$$
My question is, besides the Gaussian distribution, what other distributions can make independence and mean independence equivalent?  Or, what assumptions can we impose that would allow independence of means to be derived from independence?

Did you mean to say "Or, what assumptions can we impose that would allow independence to be derived from independence of means?"?
